# n is primitive root for odd prime p. If -n is primitive root iff p = 4k+1 for some integer k

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primitive-roots

> if $n$ is primitive root for odd prime $p$, then $-n$ is also a primitive root for $p$ $\iff p = 1 \text{ mod } 4$

I am having trouble solving this question, can someone show to me how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: If $n$ is a primitive root, then $-1\equiv n^{(p-1)/2}\pmod p$.

Comment: I know that $1 = n^{(p-1)} \text{ mod p}$, but why $-1 = n^{(p-1)/2} \text{ mod p}$ ?